# Python Scrapy - Selenium - requesting next page

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

Im trying to make a webcrawler that goes to a link and waits for the Javascript content to load. Then it should get all the links to the listed articles, before proceeding to the next page. The problem is it always scrapes from the first url ("https://techcrunch.com/search/heartbleed") instead of following the ones i gave it.  Why does the following code not scrape from the new urls i passed in the reqeusts ? I am out of ideas...

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time


class TechcrunchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "techcrunch_spider_performance"
    allowed_domains = ['techcrunch.com']
    start_urls = ['https://techcrunch.com/search/heartbleed']



    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
        #self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Sonstiges\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5)    #wartet bis zu 5 sekunden

    def parse(self, response):
        start = time.time()     #ZEITMESSUNG
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        #wartet bis zu 5 sekunden(oben definiert) auf den eintritt der condition, danach schmeist er den TimeoutException error
        try:    

            self.driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.CLASS_NAME, "block-content")))
            print("Found : block-content")

        except TimeoutException:
            self.driver.close()
            print(" block-content NOT FOUND IN TECHCRUNCH !!!")


        #Crawle durch Javascript erstellte Inhalte mit Selenium

        ahref = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//h2[@class="post-title st-result-title"]/a')

        hreflist = []
        #Alle Links zu den jeweiligen Artikeln sammeln
        for elem in ahref :
            hreflist.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))


        for elem in hreflist :
            print(elem)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=elem , callback=self.parse_content)


        #Den link fuer die naechste seite holen
        try:    
            next = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='page-link next']")
            nextpage = next.get_attribute("href")
            print("JETZT KOMMT NEXT :")
            print(nextpage)
            #newresponse = response.replace(url=nextpage)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=nextpage, dont_filter=False)

        except TimeoutException:
            self.driver.close()
            print(" NEXT NOT FOUND(OR EOF) IM CLOSING MYSELF !!!")



        end = time.time()
        print("Time elapsed : ")
        finaltime = end-start
        print(finaltime)


    def parse_content(self, response):    
        title = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h1")
        titletext = title.get_attribute("innerHTML")
        print(" h1 : ")
        print(title)
        print(titletext)
```

Answer (score 1):

One first problem would be that :

```
for elem in hreflist :
        print(elem)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=elem , callback=self.parse_content)
```

this code yield scrapy requests to all links found. But :

```
def parse_content(self, response):    
    title = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h1")
    titletext = title.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

the parse_content function try to use the driver to parse the page. You can try parsing with the response element from scrapy or load the page with the webdriver (self.driver.get(....) )

Furthermore, scrapy is asynchronous and selenium isn't. Instead of blocking after a scrapy yield Request, scrapy continues to execute the code since it's build on twisted and can launch multiple concurrent requests. The selenium driver instance won't be able to follow multiple concurrent requests from scrapy. (One lead is to replace each yield by the selenium code, even if that means losing execution time)

Comment: i added a self.driver.get(...) to parse_content, and i can get the h1-title now. Still, following to the next page doesnt work. How should i replace the yield by the selenium code ? Do you have an example ? Im not very experienced with scrapy or selenium. Thanks!

Comment: Try to replace the ` yield scrapy.Request(url=elem , callback=self.parse_content) line by the content of the function *parse_content*
For the next_page issue, you could replace the yield by a loop around all your code in parse function (**while** there is a next page, do smthg)